# Changing Devise Confirmation Link to use https

Tags: https, devise

In a Rails 3.1.1 app with Devise 1.51 I would like the confirmation link used in the confirmation message to be https instead of http. So in an email the "Confirm Link" would point to something like:

https://mysite.com/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=

I tried adding:

```
config.to_prepare { Devise::SessionsController.force_ssl }
config.to_prepare { Devise::RegistrationsController.force_ssl }
config.to_prepare { Devise::ConfirmationsController.force_ssl }
```

to config/environments/production.rb

but it did not help.  Does anyone know the proper way to do this? I know that I can go into the view at: `devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb` and substitute the confirmation_url() there but I would like to know if there is a better method to ensure everything is https (as required for my setup even though I know there is a performance hit)  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 11):

I'm using Rails 3.1.3 and Devise 1.5.2 and had the same issue, but it turns out the culprit is ActionMailer. I had to add https to ActionMailer's default_url_options

In `config/environments.production.rb`, I changed:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'mysite.com' }
```

To:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'mysite.com', :protocol => 'https' }
```

Now all of Devise's emails (confirmation, unlock, etc) use https for any links.